# Single Window WPF Application

Tags: wpf

I've created a single window application and this application has 2 screens all shown in the main window. Logon screen and then the main application screen after successful logon. I've currently achieved this by using a navigation window and pages.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach as I do not need to use the functionality provided by the navigation window (Browse back and forward et cetera).

I'm hoping someone could let me know if the navigation window is the best approach for this design or if a similar look can be achieved by not using pages and navigationwindow.

Thanks for all your help.

Emlyn

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways. One rather simple way is to remove some control from the visual tree and add another into it instead. Apart from that I have seen a number of apps using Page/Frame and it works OK.

Comment: I've tried using just changing the navigation window to a normal window and adding a frame to this and setting the frames content to my pages I've already have but this caused back / forward buttons to appear still. not sure where these were coming from. Guess they were caused by still using pages.

Comment: There should be a property on `Page` to turn off the NavigationUI

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing to stop you implementing this as two Windows.  The main window can be displayed after the completion of the succesful login from the first Window, and the first login window can be closed.

One thing you may need to be careful of is that the app doesn't exit after the first window closes but before the second is displayed.  You can set the Application [ShutdownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) property in you app.xaml if required.

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm really looking for this single window style rather than a logon window closing to show the main window. I appreciate I'm probably making things more difficult for myself but this is really the style I'm looking to achieve. I want it to be very similar to Windows messenger for example with the main content and the logon all shown in one window.

Comment: I would use a single view model which conducts two different child view models, and just injects the appropriate one into the main window content area.  With Caliburn.Micro, this is very easy, but I'm not sure if you are using a framework, or even using MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pages and navwindow if you like. This can still encompass a MVVM pattern as the Views may be loaded as pages if needed.

To start your project create one window xaml document and change the Window tag to a Navigation Window tag

```
<NavigationWindow x:Class="myapp.NavigationWindow"
xmlns:....
Title:"My App"
Source="newpage.xaml" <!--designates the page to load -->
ShowsNavigationUI="False" <!--designates if the navbar is displayed at top-->
</NavigationWindow>
```

Then within each page you can control the navigation or loading of new pages using NavigationService

```
NavigationService.Navigate(newUri("mynewpage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

If logging is not of any value for you in page navigation you can disable this in code if you need.

ps-
If you are looking for MDI WPF/win-32 does not really support MDI (Multi-document interfaces) like Delphi so for times when you need to create a MDI appearance you can use TabView controls or rely more on a pattern development MVVM which provides a more elegant means to load and pass different UI controls.